# Reactive @Input is not getting data properly in angular

Tags: angular

I have one parent component ( container.component) and one child component ( plotting.component).

From the container, the user can upload a file. one submit button will send this data into the plotting component. Unfortunately, I can send data from containers to plotting just once. If I try to upload multiple data back and forth, its not working. plotting component is not update with the proper data.

Here is my `container.component.html`:

```
   <div class="input-group">
      <div class="custom-file">
        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input inputFile" id="inputFile" (change)="upload($event.target)" />
         <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputFile">{{fileName}}</label>
       </div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary mt-2" (click)="passDAta()"> submit </button>
        
  

  <div class="card-body">
    <plotting [data]="data"></plotting>
  </div>
```

`container.ts` file:

```
data = new BehaviorSubject<any[]> ([]);
  scanData: any = [];

upload(input: HTMLInputElement) {
    const files = input.files;
    const fileToRead = files[0];

    if (fileToRead.type === "text/csv") {
      this.fileName = fileToRead.name;

      const fileReader = new FileReader();

      fileReader.onload = event => {
        const result = fileReader.result;
        if (typeof result !== "string") {
          throw new Error("Unexpected result from FileReader");
        }
        result.split("\n").map(data => {
          let [a, b] = data.split(",");
          this.scanData.push(this.p2c(parseFloat(b), parseFloat(a)));
        });
      };

      fileReader.readAsText(fileToRead, "UTF-8");
    } else {
      this.fileName = " unknow file type. csv only"
    }
  }

  passDAta() {
    this.data.next(this.scanData);
    console.log("parent: ", this.scanData)

  }
```

My `plotting component.ts` is :

```
private _data: any; 

@Input()
  set data(data: Observable<any>) {
    data.subscribe(data => {
      this._data = data;
    });
  }
  get data () {
    return this._data;
  }
```

I have tried with ngOnchanges as well. But cant detects the change. I have also created a stackbliz. you can download the csv1 and csv2. if you upload the file back and forth you will see, data is not passing into plotting from the container. How can I solve this issue?

Here is the [stackblitz](https://angular-atytrw.stackblitz.io)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `BehaviorSubject` in this case isn't elegant and might lead to too many subscriptions. You could just pass the `data` to setter and not worry about the change detection. Try the following

container component

```js
data = [];

passDAta() {
  this.data = this.scanData;
  console.log("parent: ", this.scanData)
}
```

plotting component

```js
private _data: any; 

@Input()
set data(data: any) {
  this._data = data;
}

get data () {
  return this._data;
}
```

**Update**

Old data from the variable `scanData` isn't removed before new data is pushed to it. So `@Input()` is working as expected, except the new data is getting appended to the end of the old data. You could just remove the old data using `this.scanData = [];` at the beginning of the `upload()` function. Try the following

```js
upload(input: HTMLInputElement) {
  this.scanData = [];
  .
  .
}
```

I've modified your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vduwsw).

I've removed the CSV file check in the `upload()` function in the Stackblitz to get it working. If not, it kept throwing me the ''unknown file type. csv only' error. I've also assigned the type `Array<{'x': number, 'y': number}>` to the `_data` member variable in plotting component.

Comment: i did.. but same problem. just works for the very first time. If you upload different file, plotting is not getting any. please check the stackbliz. @michael-d

Comment: I downloaded your sample CSV files and tried to upload them and got 'unknown file type. csv only' error. I am uploading CSV files.

Comment: i have upload the csv again. @michael-d 
However, still I don't know, why my code with BehaviorSubject

Comment: I've updated the code. Please see if it works for you.

Comment: I was having a nightmare. this silly mistake destroys my whole day. you just saved me. thanks a lot. answer accepted and upvoted. @michael-d